# JQuery UI Select Menu - Body width expanded

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Iam using the Jquery Select Menu Plugin to Style Select Boxes inside an HTML Table in combination with OOCSS (960px width for page).

The problem is that the plugin adds an hidden  Element for each Select Box. This works fine in most cases, but i have about 20 Selects -> so the body width is about 2000px and scrollbars appear.

Please see screnshot for Details.

[image]

Does someone knows how to handle this? I dont want to disable Scrollbars for the whole Body Tag :-)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was an bug in your css styles.

We have used "visibility:hidden" wich takes space on screen. Changed to "display:none".